# Calculating Expected Range of Scores

Tags: reliability

I have a clinical test that 35 healthy people took twice. Each test consisted of 6 trials. We measure a subject's perception of vertical. I am trying to calculate the test/retest reliability for this clinical test, but due to the nature of the test the average is not a useful measure. The test uses positive and negative numbers, they have biological importance. 0 is "normal", so a person scoring -6,+6 will look as normal as someone scoring -1,+1. An absolute average removes data as side matters-- someone answering -6,+6 will then look the same as someone scoring +6,+6 (much more consistent). Someone answering +6 multiple times, while way off traditional vertical, is fundamentally different from someone answering +6 then -6 (their perception is not constant). I would like to calculate, regardless of the average score, the expected variation in response in a healthy individual, so I can say someone who scores 0+/-6 is abnormal compared to someone who scores 0+/-1, for example. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

I have each trial for each subject and overall averages / standard deviations for all 6 trials for both tests for each subject.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to test a hypothesis on the distance between responses $d$ being abnormal vs. normal. The idea being if the distance is larger, it is more likely they are abnormal and vice versa.

Without any prior information on the distribution of abnormal people though this isn't completely solvable without making assumptions. However we can just take the uninformative prior for this which would be equal probabilities for each number, so we want to form a hypothesis on the difference $d$ where $d$ is the difference between two discrete uniform $ U(0,12)$. This distribution is some triangular distribution, so if you want a p-value of 0.05 just find the cut-off values for $95$% of this distribution and whenever your subject is outside this bound you cannot the reject the null that they are abnormal (akin to just scoring a number at random).